# Identify diode specs

Tags: diodes, voltage-regulator, identification

[image: Diode 3125]

I need help identifying this diode, I believe it to be faulty as I am getting a reading in both directions when testing with a multimeter. The markings are 3125. There is some discoloration on the PCB around this area but the voltage regulator seems to be testing fine however. Any specs or advice on what to replace this with would be appreciated, it is for a backplane on a Qnap 1079-Pro NAS not detecting any drives.

Comment: `... as I am getting a reading in both directions when testing with a multimeter` depends on what is connected in parallel. Try removing the device and take another measurement, just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

- Manufacturer: Rohm Semiconductor
- Manufacturer part number: RB051L-40 (obsolete) or RB051LAM-40 (active) or a clone of them
- [image]
- Data sheet:  [RB051L-40](https://docs.rs-online.com/4293/0900766b8101fb39.pdf), [RB051LAM-40](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/diode/schottky_barrier/rb051lam-40tr-e.pdf)
- Distributor link: [click](https://www.digikey.at/en/products/detail/rohm-semiconductor/RB051LAM-40TR/7318327?s=N4IgTCBcDaIEoCEAMBWAjAGQIIFkC0ALEiALoC%2BQA)
- Part Type: Schottky Barrier Diode
- Function on the PCBA: Possibly a bypass diode for reverse-current protection across Vout and Vin of the Anpec [APL1084](https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_1912111437_Anpec-Elec-APL1084UC-TRG_C351144.pdf) voltage regulator
- [image: List item]